# Vue JS 2 Data Object Changes However Method Doesn't Run

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following Vue JS component that I am having an issue re-rendering on data changes.

```
Vue.component('careers-list', {
  template: `
  <div id="career-list">
    <div class="context">
      <div v-for="career in careerData">
        <h1>{{ career.fields.jobTitle }}</h1>
        <div v-html="career.fields.jobDescription">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="career-pagination">
      <button>prev</button>
      <button>1</button>
      <button v-on:click="increaseCount">next</button>
    </div>
  </div>`,

  data: function() {
    return {
     careerData: [],
     paginationCount: 0
    }
  },

  created: function() {
   this.fetchData();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      client.getEntries({
        skip: this.paginationCount,
        limit: this.paginationCount + 7,
        order: 'sys.createdAt'
      })
      .then(entries => {
        this.careerData = entries.items;
        this.careerData.map(function (career) {
          career.fields.jobDescription = (marked(career.fields.jobDescription));
        });
      });
    },
    increaseCount: function() {
      this.paginationCount += 7;
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

So as you can see I have a fetchData method that fetches my data and formats it. Take a look at these lines within this method:

```
skip: this.paginationCount,
limit: this.paginationCount + 7,
```

Within my app these lines determine how many records on database will be returned. I am using a count for this within my data object `paginationCount: 0`.

I have then set an event on one of my buttons within my component template: `<button v-on:click="increaseCount">next</button>`

When this is clicked it updates the `paginationCount` using the `increaseCount` method.

When I render my application and click the button the paginationCount does increase however my `fetchData` method does not re-render the application to show the appropriate data based on the count.

I thought that Vue automatically updates any methods that have a changed data object in them however I am guessing this isn't the case or I am doing this wrong.

Any idea how I can update my `fetchData` method when the `paginationCount` is changed?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) here, which suits exactly your use-case:

> This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive operations in response to changing data.

Method is not executed as you are not returning anything from it, which depends on the vue data variable.

You have to invoke your method when `paginationCount` variable changes:

```
  data: {
     careerData: [],
     paginationCount: 0
  },
  watch: {
    // whenever paginationCount changes, this function will run
    paginationCount: function (newPaginationCount) {
       this.fetchData();
    }
  },
```