# VueJS: Setting data initially based on http response

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

So I have a template .vue file:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <textarea v-model="input" :value="input" @input="update"></textarea>
    <div v-html="compiledMarkdown"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
var markdown = require('markdown').markdown;

export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
        return {

            input: '# Some default data'
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            this.$http.get(window.location.pathname + '/data').then((response) => {
                this.input = response.body.markdown;
            }) })

    },

    computed: {
        compiledMarkdown: function() {
            this.$http.post(window.location.pathname, {
            "html": markdown.toHTML(this.input)}).then(function() {
            },function() {
            });
            return markdown.toHTML(this.input);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        update: function(e) {
            this.input = e.target.value

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In the mounted function I am trying to set input equal to the response of an HTTP request, but when you view this file `this.input` is still the same as it was initially declared. How can I change `this.input` inside the compiledMarkdown function to be `this.input` in the mounted function. What other approaches might I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call a async method from a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), you can use method or [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to run asynchronous code, from [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

> This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive operations in response to changing data.

You have to ran that relevant code when input changes, like following:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: '# Some default data',
    markdown : ''
  },
  methods: {
     fetchSchoolData: function (schoolId) {
        var url = this.buildApiUrl('/api/school-detail?schoolId=' + schoolId);
        this.$http.get(url).then(response => {
            this.schoolsListData = response.data;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, 
  },
mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        this.$http.get(window.location.pathname + '/data').then((response) => {
            this.input = response.body.markdown;
        })
      })
},
watch: {
  // whenever input changes, this function will run
  input: function (newInput) {
        this.$http.post(window.location.pathname, {
          "html": markdown.toHTML(this.input)}).then(function() {
        },function() {
          this.markdown = markdown.toHTML(this.input);
        });
  }
},
```

Have a look at my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41827591/1610034).

Comment: The watch helped me fix my problem, but the example was very confusing.